# python pandas check three element value in a row ,logic meets replace all three with one other element value

Tags: python, pandas

I think i am doing a small mistake so it is not not working

i have this data frame

```
open  high low close
0     10     0  0
1     1      1  1
0     12     0  0
0     13     0  0
```

output i wish to get is :

if a  **open ,low close value  is zero and high** is not zero replace(open,low,close) this with high value.

another option

if a **open ,low ,close is zero and high also zero replace** open and low to 1 close and high to 10

Tried this for 1 logic and am not getting through.What shall be the clean and neat solution for this.

```
> opt_ce.loc[opt_ce['open'] == 0, 'open','low','close'] = opt_ce['high']
> opt_pe.loc[opt_pe['open'] == 0, 'open', 'low', 'close'] = opt_ce['high']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
check_columns = ['open', 'low', 'close']
condition = (df[check_columns].sum(axis=1) == 0) & (df['high'] > 0)

df.loc[condition, check_columns] = df['high']
```

Output

```
   open  high  low  close
0    10    10   10     10
1     1     1    1      1
2    12    12   12     12
3    13    13   13     13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df['open'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['high'] if x['open']==x['low']==x['close']==0 else x['open'], axis=1)
df['low'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['high'] if x['open']==x['low']==x['close']==0 else x['low'], axis=1)
df['close'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['high'] if x['open']==x['low']==x['close']==0 else x['close'], axis=1)
print(df)

   open  high  low  close
0    10    10   10     10
1     1     1    1      1
2    12    12   12     12
3    13    13   13     13
```